# how to display array of object contents alphabetical order starting with small letter to capital in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want data to be displayed in alphabetical order with small letters first and then Capital letters in Angularjs controller.

alley,peter,tina,Ashton,Bob,Zenna

i have tried

```
$scope.studentData=[
   {name:'peter',age:23},
   {name:'Ashton',age:22},
   {name:'Bob',age:24},
   {name:'alley',age:26},
   {name:'Zenna',age:26},
   {name:'tina',age:26},
]



 function compareAppList(a,b) {
      if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
    return 0;
    }



 var sortedApplications = $scope.studentData.sort(compareAppList);
```

I want data to be displayed in alphabetical order with small letters first and then Capital letters in Angularjs controller.

alley,peter,tina,Ashton,Bob,Zenna

Answer (score 0):

You could check the first character and sort löower case to top, then sort with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var $scope= { studentData: [{ name: 'peter', age: 23 }, { name: 'Ashton', age: 22 }, { name: 'Bob', age: 24 }, { name: 'alley', age: 26 }, { name: 'Zenna', age: 26 }, { name: 'tina', age: 26 }] };

var names = $scope.studentData
        .map(({ name }) => name)
        .sort((a, b) => 
            (a[0].toUpperCase() === a[0]) - (b[0].toUpperCase() === b[0]) ||
            a.localeCompare(b)
        );

console.log(names);
```